# Admin Custom Page : Cannot Set Page Title in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml, page-title, title

This is my `etc/adminhtml/menu.xml`

```
<add id="My_Module::first" title="I Am Parent" module="My_Module" sortOrder="1" parent="My_Module::parent" resource="My_Module::first" />

<add id="My_Module::firstchild" title="first child" module="My_Module" sortOrder="1"  action="" parent="My_Module::first" resource="My_Module::firstchild"/>
<add id="My_Module::secondchild" title="second child" module="My_Module" sortOrder="2"  action="" parent="My_Module::first" resource="My_Module::secondchild"/>
<add id="My_Module::thirdchild" title="third child" module="My_Module" sortOrder="3"  action="module/route/index" parent="My_Module::first" resource="My_Module::thirdchild"/>
```

Now I want to change title for the **thirdchild** menu item,
so i did this from **index controller** of **thirdchild**

**index.php**

```
public function execute(){
    $this->resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();  
    $this->resultPage->setActiveMenu('My_Module::first');
    $this->resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set((__('I Am Third Child')));
    return $this->resultPage;
}
```

But it always comes with its parent title **I Am Parent**.

I also try to change title from **module_route_index.xml** like below,

```
<head>
 <title>I Am Third Child</title>
</head>
```

But it also dont works, is there any solution i can try further.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `prepend(__("My Title"));`

```
public function execute()
{
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__("My Title"));
        return $resultPage;
}
```

Comment: Working Perfectly. Thankx